# Bullet icon missing in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

While I'm trying to edit text and add there black bullets, I can't change color of bullets. As it is remains grey, but I need it to be black. Suddenly, I realized that I cant change bullet color, because the icon which is changing bullet types is missing in my SharePoint. How can I alive that icon and to take back so that I can change the color of bullet?[image]

Comment: You can't color bullets as they are plain HTML elements (<ul> and <li>), and you never could out of the box in SharePoint. You could add the character "•" and try create something that looks like a bullet-list. As it's a plain unicode character, you can color it any color you want.

Comment: But in the same page there existing black bullets, but just another paragraph bullet is grey. There should be some solution. Sorry, but I didn't understood your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes,** There is no `Color bullets selection` in the `Format Text` toolbox.

---

**Workaround**

To can customize, your bullet color, you should customize it via CSS as the following:

- From the above ribbon,> Click on `Edit source`
- Set an **ID** for your `<ul>` list

[image]

- Add the below CSS code, change the color as you prefer

  ```
  <style type="text/css"> #qassas { color:red !important; } </style>
  ```

> **Note**: you can also add the above script in Script Editor Web Part, and if you need to colorize all the list on the page, you can use this style
>
> `<style type="text/css"> ul { color:red !important; } </style>`

**OutPut**

[image]

> **Note**: the items text color will be the same bullet color, so you can
>   change it easily from the font color.